# How do I fade music in and out using Blender?

Tags: edit-mode

I am creating a youtube intro and I cannot figure out how to fade music in and out using Blender. I do not know how to do much with this program and I am not literate with this type of program. Can anyone explain in extreme detail how to fade music in and out??

Answer (score 21):

I trust your  using the video sequence editor in Blender? Load your video strip and sound/music strip into separate channels. Select the music strip press the <kbd>N</kbd> key to access the properties panel on the right hand side of the screen. Under the **Sound** tag you'll see a **Volume** slider. If you wish to fade the music in at the start, go to frame 0 and set the volume to 0 in the slider. Hover your mouse over the slider and press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to set a keyframe. The slider background should change colour, colour depends on your Blender Theme.

Now go to the point on the time line say frame 60 and set the volume to 1 or what ever level you would like at this point and hover the mouse over the volume slider and press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to set another keyframe. The music will fade in from 0 - 1 over these frames.

Fading out is the reverse process, go to where you want the fade to start; make sure the volume is level 1 hover over the slider and press I to set a keyframe. then go to the end of the clip set the volume to '0' and set another keyframe.

Note if you don't set the key frame to 1 near the end of the clip the volume will fade from the first keyframe set to 1 at the beginning down to 0 for the keyframe at a the end.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the easiest way is to:

1) Make a soft cut of ANY audio (can be the one you want to fade).

2) Move it to another layer, and make sure it overlaps the frames of the audio you want to fade.

3) Edit the moved audio strip so the sound is muted.

4) <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the audio strip you want to fade, THEN the muted strip.

5) In video sequence editor, click "strip" icon, then click "cross fade sounds".

You basically just created a black track, and used blender's built in cross fade effect.